# Java 8 code to concatenate a List of Strings without duplicates

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collect

I have a `Hit` class and a `List<Hit>` that contains something like this:

```
{{id=1, list="EU"}, {id=2, list="EU,OF,UN"}}
```

How can I get some concatenated lists without doubled occurrences?

I tried something like this:

```
Set<String> sourceList = alertHit.stream()
                .map(Hit::getList)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but I get "EU, EU,OF,UN" in my `sourceList` `Set`. How can I get only "EU,OF,UN" in my `Set`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Hit::getList` returns a `String` of comma separated elements, you have to split that `String`.

This will produce a `String[]` which can be used to produce a `Stream<String>`.

Finally, you need to use `flatMap` instead of `map` in order to get a flat `Stream` of all those `String`s. That's the `Stream` you should collect into a `Set`.

```
Set<String> sourceList = 
    alertHit.stream()
            .flatMap(h -> Arrays.stream(h.getList().split(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thanks, I was urgently needed to fix this and didn't have the time to learn all about the java 8 changes, I will look over .flatMap.